# How to convert words into numbers in android

Tags: android, int

I am new to android and really appreciate your help in this =)

I am trying to convert various words that had been chosen by the user via spinners into numbers for calculations.

I dont know how to go about doing this and had been at it for 2 days already.

Below is the code. (I know that it is wrong because I used another BMI guide to help build the codes below, however, since the data entered by the users were numbers in the first place, it differs from my case.)

Once again thank you all very much for the help, truly appreciate it.

```
package com.example.mygpa;

public class Main extends Activity {

    // declare the references for the UI elements
    Spinner courseSpinner;
    Spinner semesterSpinner;
    EditText currentGPA;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint ("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Spinner Course_Add_Spinner = Create_Course_Add_Spinner();
            Spinner Semester_Add_Spinner = Create_Semester_Add_Spinner(null);

            // load the references to the widgets 
            courseSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_course);
            semesterSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_semester);
            currentGPA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.current_gpa);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

     // handler that we defined in "onClick" attribute of the button
        // get called when the button is clicked
        public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
            // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button
            if (view.getId() == R.id.btncalculate) {

                int course = getSelectedCourse();
                int semester = getSelectedSemester();
                int gpavalue = Integer.parseInt(currentGPA.getText().toString());

                int gpaValue = (((gpavalue / course) + (semester*4)) / (course+semester));

                Intent intent = new Intent (Main.this, Main2.class);
                intent.putExtra("GpaValue", gpaValue);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        public int getSelectedCourse() {

            try
            {
            String Text = courseSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String Text2 = semesterSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int value = Integer.parseInt(Text);
            int value2 = Integer.parseInt(Text2);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if (courseSpinner.equals("Hospitality and Tourism Management") && semesterSpinner.equals("Year 1 Semester 1")) {
                return (int) (0);
            } else if  (courseSpinner.equals("Hospitality and Tourism Management") && semesterSpinner.equals("Year 1 Semester 2")) {
                return (int) (22);
            } else if  (courseSpinner.equals("Hospitality and Tourism Management") && semesterSpinner.equals("Year 2 Semester 1")) {
                return (int) (44);
            } else if  (courseSpinner.equals("Hospitality and Tourism Management") && semesterSpinner.equals("Year 2 Semester 2")) {
                return (int) (62);
            } else if  (courseSpinner.equals("Hospitality and Tourism Management") && semesterSpinner.equals("Year 3 Semester 1")) {
                return (int) (77);
            } else {
                return (int) (101);
            }
        }

        public int getSelectedSemester() {

            try
            {

                String Text = semesterSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int value = Integer.parseInt(Text);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                if (semesterSpinner.equals("Year 1 Semester 1")) {
                    return (int) (22);
                } else if  (semesterSpinner.equals("Year 1 Semester 2")) {
                    return (int) (22);
                } else if  (semesterSpinner.equals("Year 2 Semester 1")) {
                    return (int) (18);
                } else if  (semesterSpinner.equals("Year 2 Semester 2")) {
                    return (int) (15);
                } else if  (semesterSpinner.equals("Year 3 Semester 1")) {
                    return (int) (24);
                } else {
                    return (int) (18);
                }   
        }

    // Creates the Course Spinner for the Add section sends the choice made to
    // a method for populating the Semester spinner
    public Spinner Create_Course_Add_Spinner() {
        Spinner Course_Add_Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_course);
        String[] Course_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.course_array);
        SpinnerAdapter Course_Add_Spinner_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Course_Add_Spinner_Array);
        Course_Add_Spinner.setAdapter(Course_Add_Spinner_Adapter);
        Course_Add_Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Course_Add_Spinner_Listener());
        return Course_Add_Spinner;
    }

    // The listener for the Course Spinner that sends whatever choice made to
    // the method that populates the second spinner.
    public class Course_Add_Spinner_Listener implements
            OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> Course_Add_Adapter_View, View v, int position, long row) {
            String Course_Add_Choice = Course_Add_Adapter_View.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Create_Semester_Add_Spinner(Course_Add_Choice);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    // Create the Semester Spinner for the Add section
    public Spinner Create_Semester_Add_Spinner(String course_array) {
        String[] Semester_Add_Spinner_Array = null;
        Spinner Semester_Add_Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_semester);

        if (course_array.equals("Hospitality and Tourism Management")) {
            Semester_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HTM);

        } else if (course_array.equals("Sports and Wellness")) {
            Semester_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SW);

        } else Semester_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HTM);

        SpinnerAdapter Semester_Add_Spinner_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Semester_Add_Spinner_Array);
        Semester_Add_Spinner.setAdapter(Semester_Add_Spinner_Adapter);
        return Semester_Add_Spinner;
        }
}
```

As requested, the log cat report where the error occured.

```
04-20 23:30:13.759: W/dalvikvm(26872): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a96930)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17360)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    ... 11 more
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at com.example.mygpa.Main.getSelectedCourse(Main.java:73)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    at com.example.mygpa.Main.calculateClickHandler(Main.java:57)
04-20 23:30:13.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26872):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt(mystring);

Comment: Hi,o can you please elaborate on where I should put that code? thanks!

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 2):

```
myInteger = Integer.parseInt(myString);
```

Comment: im sorry, can you please elaborate on it on where i should put that code? should it be under the "else if" lines? thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from spinner and use the value as below.

```
try
{
     Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
     String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
     int value= Integer.parseInt(Text);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, the values from the spinners are words, how do i convert them into numbers for calculation purposes?

Comment: Sorry for the double post.
An example is that if the user selects "Year 1 Semester 1" in the spinner, I want that word to represent number 22 which i will use for a calculation

Comment: what you have done should work. What is the problem then? Where is the need to convert words to numbers?

Comment: I have updated the codes. It will still crash when I calculate. Is it because my input for the currentGPA is in decimals? Or am I not using your suggested codes correctly?

I am truly embarrassed with this because to you all this must be a very noobish mistake, but thanks for helping me along the way!

Comment: if there is a crash there must be some exceptions logged in logcat can you post the same?

Comment: does your spinner have numbers?? post logcat.

Comment: Well the semester spinner does have numbers, but it is in the form of "Year 1 Semester 1", "Year 2 Semester 2" and so on, I have added the log cat above.